# gzip -d introduces wrong ASCII characters

Tags: linux, docker, compression, gzip

I am struggling with the following command: `gzip -d /path/to/compressed.sql.gz`

I always run it inside a container from the same Docker image. It works fine on my laptop as well as in our production server. However, in a new computer it **always** produces an invalid uncompressed file that contains weird ASCII characters (for instance, it introduces `!` not present in the original file).

Here are the steps to reproduce the error:

```
wget http://static.sing-group.org/EvoPPI/db/sql/2022.04/evoppi.sql.gz -O test.sql.gz
gzip -t test.sql.gz
zgrep -a '!' test.sql.gz
gzip -c -d test.sql.gz > test.sql
grep '!' test.sql
```

It works fine on my computer with `wget 1.19.4` and `gzip 1.6` (these versions can be found also in a base Docker image of `ubuntu:18.04`). The `gzip -t` command does not find any error, decompression runs without errors and the final `grep` does not find any `!`, which means that the file is OK because it does not contain that character.

However, it does not work in another computer with `wget 1.20.3` and `gzip 1.10`. Even when `gzip -t` says that the file is OK and `gzip -d` does not raise any error, the final `grep` always shows weird ASCII characters and the `!` not present in the original file.

What seems even stranger for me is that in those computer also fails when running the commands through the Docker image of `ubuntu:18.04` (i.e. using same versions of wget and gzip than in my computer).

Thanks in advance!!

#### sha256 as suggested by Bib

Computer 1 (my laptop):

```
f7348471a3900e7e2a0dc521be4d25c1adcfce851b545318a52fa034e908826d  test.sql.gz
83456ec6f3b4ee0344a87bcd711ab1dca8ca8dffd7135958f7cbb311a3186649  test.sql
```

Computer 2:

```
f7348471a3900e7e2a0dc521be4d25c1adcfce851b545318a52fa034e908826d  test.sql.gz (matches Computer 1)
9c10d434a3c7b28f5f385bf0a333acce9ea918bf38c47aa5685bff2153fa0386  test.sql (does not match Computer 1)
```

Comment: Could you try to just compress the small section of the sql file around a point that is not correctly decompressed and provide it and the compressed file as a minimal working example?

Comment: Thanks @Robert 

I have edited the original post to add the commands I use and give more details about the tests I have performed so far.

Comment: Run sha256 against the compressed file on all systems and compare, that could rule out wget. Decompress the file on all systems then run sha256 against them and compare.

Comment: I have added them to the answer. The compressed files have the same sha256sum, so I think wget is working properly.

Comment: Now run `head` against them both and do a visual compare, then run `diff`. One of them isn't on an ebcdic system where there is some form of translation going on?

Comment: The first 100 and last 100 lines of both uncompressed files are exactly the same (checked with `diff`). I can't run the `diff` to compare the full files because they are in different computers and the file has 21.5GB (172 304 148 lines). I can find a region in the middle of the file where lines are changed (with `grep -n -a '!' 002.sql`). However, when I extract it with `sed -n '44275150,44275210p' 002.sql > 002-middle.sql` the file I obtain is no longer identified as ASCII but as data (in my computer works fine of course). We are not using ebcdic systems.